# How to wait for a css attribute to change?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I tell Selenium webdriver to wait on a specific element to have a specific attribute set in css?

I want to wait for:

```
element.getCssValue("display").equalsIgnoreCase("block")
```

Usually one waits for elements to be present like this:

```
webdriver.wait().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("some_input")));
```

How can I wait for the specific css value of `display` attribute?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this would work for you.

```
webdriver.wait().until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='some_input'][contains(@style, 'display: block')]")));
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work `//span[contains(text(),'Create Professor')][contains(@style,'color: #222222')]`  . It is giving element not found exception. Where HTML was `<span class="menu-item" id="professor-create">Click here to Create Professor...</span>`. Create Profressor turns from disabled (grey text) to black bold text

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would *not* work because JS changes to the style do not change the value of @style. OP needs just a plain old wait loop on `element.getCssValue("display")`.

Answer (score 1):

Small modification of the above answer helpped for me. I had to use two `(`s before I start `By.XPATH`, not 1:

```java
WebDriverWait(browser,1000).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,xpathstring)))
```

Comment: this answer is for Python, as a FYI

Answer (score 1):

In C# with extension method:

```
public static WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(SeleniumInfo.Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    public static void WaitUntilAttributeValueEquals(this IWebElement webElement, String attributeName, String attributeValue)
        {            
                wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
                {
                    if (webElement.GetAttribute(attributeName) == attributeValue)
                    {
                        return webElement;
                    }
                    return null;
                });
        }
```

Usage:

```
IWebElement x = SeleniumInfo.Driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//..."));
x.WaitUntilAttributeValueEquals("disabled", null); //Verifies that the attribute "disabled" does not exist
x.WaitUntilAttributeValueEquals("style", "display: none;");
```